# Как повлиять на элемент?

Tags: jquery

Хочу чтобы в каждом отдельном Wrapper при нажатии Add менялось на Del и наоборот.
У меня с моим кодом, это срабатывает только на первый Wrapper, в остальных не срабатывает. В чем ошибка?

**Есть структура:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.Add').click(function(event) {
    sendPost('/add?id=' + $(this).attr('docId'), function() {
      console.log(window.myAdd);
      $('#' + $('.Del').attr('id')).show();
      $('#' + $('.Add').attr('id')).hide();
    });
  });

  $('.Del').click(function(event) {
    sendPost('/del?id=' + $(this).attr('docId'), function() {
      $('#' + $('.Add').attr('id')).show();
      $('#' + $('.Del').attr('id')).hide();
    });
  });


  function sendPost(url, action) {
    $.post(url, function(data) {
      if (data.result == true) {
        action();
      }
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="Add" id="Add1" style="display: block;">Add</p>
  <p class="Del" id="Del1" style="display: none;">Delete</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="Add" id="Add2" style="display: block;">Add</p>
  <p class="Del" id="Del2" style="display: none;">Delete</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="Add" id="Add3" style="display: block;">Add</p>
  <p class="Del" id="Del3" style="display: none;">Delete</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="Add" id="Add4" style="display: block;">Add</p>
  <p class="Del" id="Del4" style="display: none;">Delete</p>
</div>
```

Comment: lexxl, что это значит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.Del')` выбирает все элементы с классом `'Del'`, a `$('.Del').attr('id')` возвращает значение атрибута `id` первого элемента в этой выборке.

```
$('.Add').click(function(event){
  var $target = $(this);
  sendPost('/add?id=' + $target.attr('docId'), function() {
    $target.closest(".wrapper").find(".Del").show();
    $target.hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Вы мне очень помогли, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Fitstd - На здоровье. Успешного программирования!

Comment: все отлично работает, если не сложно, то подкорректируйте мое понимание написанного: 
При нажатии на элемент с классом .Add запускается функция:
1. создается переменная $target которая по сути та же самая $(this) (это было для удобства сделано?)
2. Отправляется  Post запрос с docId элемента .Add
3. в .Add функция closest будет искать первый попавшийся элемент с классом .wrapper, а в нем функция find найдет элемент .Del и покажет его, а .Add скроет.

Так?

Comment: @Fitstd "первый попавшийся элемент с классом .wrapper" - в цепочке родителей элемента target, от него и вверх. Переменная `$target` заведена, так как `this` внутри анонимной функции поданной в `sendPost` будет не тем, что внутри обработчика `click`.

Comment: еще раз спасибо, уже понятно!
А чем является this внутри sendPost?

Comment: @Fitstd В соответствии с Вашим вызовом `action();`, `this` *внутри анонимной функции поданной в `sendPost`* будет `window`.